# Upper and lower quantiles

Tags: quantiles

I have a question regarding upper and lower quantiles.

In my lecture notes these are defined as:

$Q_p[X] = \inf\{x \mid P(X \leq x) \geq p\}$
is the lower p-quantile

$Q^p[X] = \inf\{x \mid P(X \leq x) > p\}$
is the upper p-quantile

For which distributions does $Q_p[X] = Q^p[X]$?

I can see that for continuous distributions with strictly increasing cdf the equality holds. But is it true for general continous r.v. $X$? If not, are there well known continous distributions where $Q_p[X] \neq Q^p[X]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a continuous but not *strictly* increasing CDF on the unit interval, defined in the obvious way:

[image: CDF]

We have

$$ Q_\frac{1}{2}[X] = \frac{1}{3} \quad\text{and}\quad Q^\frac{1}{2}[X] = \frac{2}{3}. $$

Whether this toy example is "well known" enough is of course debatable, but it can easily arise as the empirical CDF of a sample from a (hypothesized) continuous distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephan Kolassa. With "well known" I meant a distribution that has a name like normal/exponential/lognormal/(...)-distribution.